# Allow IP addresses to bypass authentication in Nginx auth_request module

Tags: nginx, whitelist

I have a config like below. I would like to allow a list of IPs to bypass authentication.

```
server {
 listen 80;

 server_name test2.example.com;
 add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=2592000;

  location = /oauth2/auth {
      internal;
      proxy_pass http://oauth.example.com:4180;
  }

  location /oauth2/ {
      proxy_pass http://oauth.example.com:4180;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
  }

  location / {
    auth_request /oauth2/auth;
    error_page 401 = /oauth2/start?rd=$request_uri;
    proxy_pass https://test.example.com;
  }
}
```

I have tried adding this above `auth_request` but that doesn't seem to help. I can see in the logs that the request is coming from whitelisted IPs.

```
satisfy all;
allow 10.0.0.0/16;
allow 56.56.56.56/28;
deny all;
```

Update:
Modifying `satisfy all` to `satisfy any` fixed the bypassing for IP addresses.

Comment: Try: `satisfy any;` instead of `satisfy all;` - see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#satisfy).

Comment: @RichardSmith that worked. thank you so much!